# Undefined offset: 0-wp-includes/meta.php:488 -Melding

Tags: php, meta-query

When i made a changes to  `$parents to $parents[]`

```
public static function get_parents($post_id = false){
        if (!$post_id){
            $post_id = get_the_ID();
        }
        if (!$post_id){
            global $wpdb;
            if ($wpdb->last_result && count($wpdb->last_result) == 1){
                $post_id = $wpdb->last_result[0]->ID;
            }
        }
        $parents[]= get_metadata('post', $post_id, WPKWP::$META_CHILD, false);
        $something=count($parents);
        if (count($parents) > 0){
            return $parents;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Query Monitor plugin shows 
**Undefined offset: 0-wp-includes/meta.php:488 -Melding**

This code below seems to be the problem. if i set the last line  `return $meta;` to `return null;` error seems to go away.

```
public static function get_post_metadata($meta_value, $post_id, $meta_key, $single){
        if (is_admin()){
            return null;
        }

        remove_filter('get_post_metadata', array(WPKWP::CLASS_NAME, 'get_post_metadata'), 0);
        $child_meta = get_metadata('post', $post_id, $meta_key, false);
        if (WPKWP::get_parent()){
            $parent_meta = get_metadata('post', WPKWP::get_parent(), $meta_key, false);

            if (is_array($parent_meta) && is_array($child_meta)) {
                $meta = array_merge($parent_meta, $child_meta);
            } else {
                $meta = $parent_meta;
            }
        } else {
            $meta = $child_meta;
        }
        add_filter('get_post_metadata', array(WPKWP::CLASS_NAME, 'get_post_metadata'), 0, 4);
        return $meta;
    }
```

Comment: Do you really think that anybody will analyze this amount of code just to answer your question? O_o

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż sorry Any suggestions will help

Comment: Its hard to suggest anything when you post so much code...

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż hello.i have reduced the code. i think problem origins from the code shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `$parents[]` to `$parents` in get_parents() function:

```
$parents = get_metadata('post', $post_id, WPKWP::$META_CHILD, false);
if ($parents !== FALSE && count($parents) > 0)
    return $parents;
return false;
```

because `get_metadata` return array in this case. If the `$post_id` parameter is invalid, `false` is returned. If the meta value isn't set, function return an empty array.
Therefore, `$parents` array always will contain one element - false, empty array or array with values. The condition `count($parents) > 0` is always true.

Define variable `$meta = null;` before `if (WPKWP::get_parent())`. If condition is true then only local `$meta` variable (invisible in return line) is created.

You define function `get_parents` but in `get_post_metadata()` you have `WPKWP::get_parent()`.

Comment: Hello i tried this but does not work. WPKWP::get_parent() also exists...i haven't added it to make the problem less complected